# How can I save a document from Pages in RTF format?

Tags: pages, iwork

I only found descriptions were you use the export function of Pages. But there is no RTF option anymore. So is it possible to export a Pages file to RTF?

Answer (score 1):

One work around you may find helpful uses the previous version of **Pages** which should still be in your **Applications** folder unless you removed it.

- Open your document in **Pages** version 5.
- Next, use the **Export** dialog to export to **Pages '09**
- Then, open the document with **Pages '09**
- Now, export to **RTF**

Bit of a pain, but not too much effort.

[image: Export Pages 09 to RTF]

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that is not possible anymore in Pages 5. [Here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6569681) alternative programs are proposed. TextEdit is not an option for me because I need header/footers.